# cannot install firebase tools

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm using Mac OS 10.15.2, Terminal 2.10.

I'm trying to install firebase tools to allow me to upload my experiment to firebase.
The following is what I used to do, which had been giving me success. But today, I'm using a new computer, and the installations were unsuccessful. I'm pasting the record in command line, as a screenshot, here for your reference

[image: Screenshot].

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don't run the command as `sudo` as it leads to all kinds of security problems. If you get an error when running without `sudo`, have a look here: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally If you still have problems installing after following that advice, post the updated steps please. In that case, please post the actual text and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong package.  You should be using "firebase-tools" instead of "firebase-cli".  Be sure to read through the warnings and errors carefully.

Uninstall the old firebase-cli package:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g firebase-cli
```

Then install the correct firebase-tools package:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running the command with sudo i.e use the command

sudo npm install -g firebase-tools